# Azure WebJobs Deployment with Continuous Integration on Visual Studio Online

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-webjobs

Friends,

I am trying to setup Continuous Integration with Azure WebJobs. I have a Web and a WebJobs project in the solution. I have continuous integration and deployment already setup for the web app in Visual Studio Online (*.visualstudio.com). 
I also connected the WebJobs and the Web app using the Visual Studio ASP.Net extensions - Right click the WebSite project in VS 2013 > Add > Existing Azure WebJob project. It created webjobs-list.json file in the website project.

I was expecting that when the Web app deployment happens to Azure Website after the Visual Studio Online build, it will deploy the WebJobs too. But it is not doing so.

How do we automate the WebJobs deployment after Visual Studio Online build in visualstudio.com?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The WTE team is aware of the TFS publishing issues. I've been personally working on developing a workaround with which I'm comfortable but haven't finalized it yet. My team is working on an improvement to the WebJobs publishing experience from VSO. This item is absolutely on our agenda to repair, and will be included in the next VS update. In the meantime I'm trying to come up with a workaround for the time being; once that workaround is prescriptive enough to post, I'll write a post summarizing the process on our team blog.

Comment: Do you have a URL for the team blog so we know where to keep an eye out? Thanks!

Comment: Absolutely - here you go: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/. I'll either have a post out this weekend on this or be able to provide a preliminary ETA on a fix next week.

Comment: An update on this issue would really be appreciated as this is exactly my issue at the moment.

Comment: It's not working for me either, adding a "Publish as Azure WebJob" profile seems to not work and also break my website's post-build publish.  Are there any solutions?

Comment: I also have this problem and a solution would be much appreciated.

Comment: UPDATE https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/enabling-command-line-or-continuous-delivery-of-azure-webjobs/

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the way to do it with VSTS

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2016/05/18/deploying-and-schedule-azure-webjobs-from-vsts-to-azure-web-app-with-bonus-cron-scheduling/

Basically,

1. Use VS to link your web job to a web app.
2. Create a new Buildtask that uploads the WebJob.zip file.
3. Profit.